# How to turn flat MySQL data into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I got this data from a MySQL SELECT query...

```
+--------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+
| vid_id | vid_name | file_id | file_url     | tag_name       |
+--------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+
|      1 | Video 1  |       1 | video_1.mp4  | Lorem ipsum    |
|      1 | Video 1  |       2 | video_1.webm | Lorem ipsum    |
|      2 | Video 2  |       3 | video_2.mp4  | Dolor sit amet |
|      2 | Video 2  |       4 | video_2.webm | Dolor sit amet |
+--------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+
```

... which I'm trying to get into a multidimension PHP array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Video 1
            [tag] => Lorem ipsum
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => video_1.mp4
                    [1] => video_1.webm
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Video 2
            [tag] => Dolor sit amet
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => video_2.mp4
                    [1] => video_2.webm
                )
        )
)
```

I get close when I use a use a variable to check if the video name has already been added to the array. However, I can't figure out how to then only add the video file to a nested array on the next iteration. This is my best attempt so far:

```
<?php
    // Define a variable to keep track of iterations:
    $title = '';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

        if ($title != $row['vid_name']) {
            // Grab all the data:
            $video_data[] = array(
                'name' => $row['vid_name'],
                'tag' => $row['tag_name'],
                $files = array(
                    'file' => $row['file_url']
                )
            );
        } else {
            // Grab only the file URL and add it to the files array:
            $files[] = $row['file_url'];
        }

        // Update the tracking variable:
        $title = $row['vid_name'];
    }
?>
```

This doesn't work:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Video 1
            [tag] => Lorem ipsum
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => video_1.mp4
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Video 2
            [tag] => Dolor sit amet 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => video_2.mp4
                )
        )
)
```

I'm sure that what I'm trying to achieve is possible but I don't have enough knowledge of PHP to figure this one out (and I suspect there are better ways to get the array I want). Suggestions and pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the vid_id or vid_name (if unique) as the first array key?

Check if the vid_id exists in the array, if not, add the details, and add every file corresponding to that vid_id under that key.

```
$video_data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

    $key = $row['vid_id'];

    // Add details if they don't exist yet
    if (!isset($video_data[$key])) {
        $video_data[$key] = [
            'name' => $row['vid_name'],
             'tag' => $row['tag_name']
        ];
    }
    // Always add file
    $video_data[$key]['files'][] = $row['file_url'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that does the trick. There is a small error though: the if statement is missing a closing bracket (I tried to edit your answer but it wouldn't let me). Anyway - I'll accept your answer in a minute.

Comment: @rkhff fixed,  was missing a parenthesis before the opening bracket.